# Why does task.Wait not deadlock on a non-ui thread? Or am I just lucky?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, deadlock, async-await

First a small bit of background information. I am in the process of making existing C# library code suitable for execution on WinRT. As a minor part of this code deep down needs to do a little file IO, we first tried to keep things synchronous and used Task.Wait() to stop the main thread until all IO was done.

Sure enough, we quickly found out that leads to a deadlock.

I then found myself changing a lot of code in a prototype to make it "asynchronous". That is, I was inserting async and await keywords, and I was changing the method return types accordingly. This was a lot of work - too much senseless work in fact -, but I got the prototype working this way.

Then I did an experiment, and I ran the *original code with the Wait statement* on a separate thread:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=> Draw(..., cancellationToken)
```

No deadlock!

Now I am seriously confused, because I thought that I understood how async programming works. Our code does not (yet) use ConfigureAwait(false) at all. So all await statements should continue in the same context as they got invoked in. Right? I *assumed* that that means: *the same thread*. Now if this thread has invoked "Wait", this should also lead to a deadlock. But it does not.

Do any of you have a clear rock-solid explanation?

The answer to this will determine whether I will really go through messing up our code by inserting a lot of conditional async/await keywords, or whether I will keep it clean and just use a thread that does a Wait() here and there. If the continuations get run by an arbitrary non-blocked thread, things should be fine. However, if they get run by the UI thread, we may be in trouble if the continuation is computationally expensive.

I hope that the issue is clear. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have an [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog, where I explain exactly what the context is:

It is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. Note: if there is no current `TaskScheduler`, then `TaskScheduler.Current` is the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`, which is the thread pool task scheduler.

In today's code, it usually just comes down to whether or not you have a `SynchronizationContext`; task schedulers aren't used a whole lot today (but will probably become more common in the future). I have an [article on `SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) that describes how it works and some of the implementations provided by .NET.

WinRT and other UI frameworks (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight) all provide a `SynchronizationContext` for their main UI thread. This context represents just the single thread, so if you mix blocking and asynchronous code, you can quickly encounter deadlocks. I describe why this happens in more detail [in a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but in summary the reason why it deadlocks is because the `async` method is attempting to re-enter its `SynchronizationContext` (in this case, resume executing on the UI thread), but the UI thread is blocked waiting for that `async` method to complete.

The thread pool does not have a `SynchronizationContext` (or `TaskScheduler`, normally). So if you are executing on a thread pool thread and block on asynchronous code, it will not deadlock. This is because the context captured is the thread pool context (which is not tied to a particular thread), so the `async` method can re-enter its context (by just running on a thread pool thread) while another thread pool thread is blocked waiting for it to complete.

> The answer to this will determine whether I will really go through messing up our code by inserting a lot of conditional async/await keywords, or whether I will keep it clean and just use a thread that does a Wait() here and there.

If your code is `async` all the way, it shouldn't look messy at all. I'm not sure what you mean by "conditional"; I would just make it all `async`. `await` has a "fast path" implementation that makes it synchronous if the operation has already completed.

Blocking on the asynchronous code using a background thread is possible, but it has some caveats:

1. You don't have the UI context, so you can't do a lot of UI things.
2. You still have to "sync up" to the UI thread, and your UI thread should not block (e.g., it should `await Task.Run(..)`, not `Task.Run(..).Wait()`). This is particularly true for WinRT apps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This explains quite a lot.

Comment: As to messing things up: this is existing library code that is targetted at multiple (.Net) platforms, not just WinRT. We would like to use the same code for all platforms, so we have to use #if to avoid await/async for platforms where it is not available. In addition, we cannot just change all of the existing API's into asynchronous ones, as that would break things for existing customers. All these #if statements make the code quite a bit less readable.

Comment: I find the _idea_ of async/await quite attractive and sensible. However, the actual implementation that Microsoft provides is troublesome I think. The fact that the semantics of these constructs depends on the context in which the thread was started is a mistake I think. Mainly because semantics of program code should depend on runtime context as little as possible (hard to reason about). I can understand that Microsoft wants to add options, but I think that straightforward use of await and sync should not introduce such differences.

Comment: ...In fact, given that the compiler is so good at telling me where to put async and await, it might have been wiser if users were not forced to put them in their code at all, and make sure that the implementation followed some consistent, conservative semantics. Or... if await had been a method call, I could have created an identity function for older platforms... MS certainly has not made things easy in this respect.

Comment: @MarcoKesseler: The `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package enables `async` for PCLs across most modern platforms. Regarding the decisions around keywords, I collected a lot of that rationale [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html). Regarding the context, I would also prefer that the default is to discard the context, but that would make it harder for most newcomers. Overall, I think `async` is as easy as it can be; there are no improvements I can think of that would not cause even worse problems in other scenarios.

Comment: I think your blog is a great resource for information. However: 1) I am not sure that discarding the context would be a good default, as that it troublesome for UI threads. 2) I have seen no discussion about syntactical alternatives to using keywords, or I missed something. 3) I think that the reasons I have seen for _not_ inferring await/async are rather weak: inferring does not prohibit additional syntax for specifying behavior that deviates from the default and 4)...

Comment: ...4) these comments are probably not the right place for a discussion, but... I was actually wondering why the compiler cannot infer wait/async an accompanying types _internally_ and not bother us with it by default. A programmer does not _have_ to see the Task type, similar to not seeing stack frames. In many situations it is an implementation detail (I have a background in functional language compiler technology on parallel hardware by the way, in case you wonder where these "hunches" come from).

Comment: @MarcoKesseler: In my last comment I have a link to my blog that explains why `async`/`await`/`Task` cannot be inferred. There are lots of links from that post to discussions around the web from when Async was in a CTP stage.

Comment: I did read your blog and some of the links. Unfortunately the listed arguments do not really convince me. I could of course be wrong. One way to find out would be to write down my own arguments in a blog of my own (or so). At the same time I am a bit reluctant, because that will take time and I do not have the illusion that this will change things one bit.

Comment: [This](http://notadot.blogspot.nl/2013/08/async-task-designforemperor-return.html) is my view I am afraid.